# How can I update "last_updated" field, whenever user changes data

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-models, django-rest-framework

I am trying to make a custom user model in django and adding the additional field "last_updated" which is supposed to update the date and time whenever a user makes changes or saves new data.

```
class User(AbstractUser):
    username = None 
    email = models.EmailField(_('email address'), unique=True)
    photo = models.ImageField(upload_to='avatars/', null=True, blank=True)
    last_updated = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True) #defining field in the model.


    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = []

    objects = UserManager()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.email
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried overriding save method of User:

```
from datetime import datetime

class User(AbstractUser):
    # rest of code

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
       self.last_update = datetime.now()
       super(User, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Answer (score 1):

Wouldn't it be easier to use `auto_now=True` ?

So your model could look like below:

```
class User(AbstractUser):
    username = None 
    email = models.EmailField(_('email address'), unique=True)
    photo = models.ImageField(upload_to='avatars/', null=True, blank=True)
    last_updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True) #defining field in the model.


    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = []

    objects = UserManager()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.email
```

This would help you have lesser code, and use inbuilt functionality of Django.